# Apache Toree Syntax Highlighting for Scala

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

The syntax highlighting for "Apache Toree - Scala" doesn't work correctly. When I write some code in the cell, Jupyter doesn't highlight it.

[image]

However, when I refresh the notebook, it highlights everything:
[image]

I have already configured `kernel.json` file, but it didn't help.
Anybody knows a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Same here, any solution?

Comment: The `spark` kernel is working presently but the `pyspark` has *zero* highlighting - as of fresh installs in Nov 18.  I have tried both `jupyter install toree` and `pip3 install toree`: both have same result

Comment: Using Toree 0.1.0, same problem here

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved in the most recent release candidate of Toree. Try re-installing it with

```
pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0-incubating-rc2/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.tar.gz
```